# Explanation of code involving function pointers and state machine

Tags: c, function-pointers, state-machine

Can someone explain this line by line (character by character maybe, haha)?

```
typedef int (*funcptr)();     /* generic function pointer */
typedef funcptr (*ptrfuncptr)();  /* ptr to fcn returning g.f.p. */

funcptr start(), stop();
funcptr state1(), state2(), state3();

void statemachine()
{
    ptrfuncptr state = start;

    while(state != stop)
        state = (ptrfuncptr)(*state)();
}

funcptr start()
{
    return (funcptr)state1;
}
```

For example, I would like to know why there are () at the end of line 1. An answer like "that's just how you declare a pointer to a function" would be satisfying, but then when you declare a variable of that type, why only use "funcptr" without the ()?

Lines 4 and 5. Why do you have the () here? Those aren't functions, they're pointers to functions, right?

Line 9. Why doesn't "state" have ()? Still a pointer to a function as are the ones on lines 5 and 6.

Line 9. What is "start" without the ()?

Line 12. WHAT?! (I know what typecasting is. At least I think I do...)

Line 17. Why does "state1" require a typecast? It is of the type it's being cast as already. Or is it because it's missing the ()?

It would really help me to understand these concepts.

PS. This is for a microcontroller I'll use in an electronic Dummy Load I'm designing. Figured it's a good opportunity to learn more about C. The code is from http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the question, this comes from the C FAQs web site.  The question is:

> Q: How can I declare a function that can return a pointer to a function of the same type? I'm building a state machine with one function for each state, each of which returns a pointer to the function for the next state. But I can't find a way to declare the functions—I seem to need a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function returning a pointer to a function…, ad infinitum.
>
> A: You can't quite do it directly. One way is to have the function return a generic function pointer (see question 4.13), with some judicious casts to adjust the types as the pointers are passed around:

And then there's a first example using the code shown in the SO question.

As the FAQ answer says, you can't create a function that returns a pointer to its own type of function, so you have to bludgeon the compiler into working.

#### Line 1: `typedef int (*funcptr)();`

This has the `()` at the end because without them, you'd have `typedef int (*intptr);` or `typedef int *intptr;` which is not what you want.  The empty parentheses are an indeterminate — not empty — list of arguments.  It *is* the way you declare a function pointer — before even trying to compile with my default compilation options, I modified the code to: `typedef int (*funcptr)(void);`.

A `funcptr`, therefore, is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and (at least for the purposes of this discussion) takes no arguments.

#### Line 2: `typedef funcptr (*ptrfuncptr)();`

Don't try this without the intermediate type!  This too is a pointer to a function, and the function returns a `funcptr` — and I used `typedef funcptr (*ptrfuncptr)(void);` to assert 'and takes no arguments'.

#### Line 4 & 5: `funcptr start(), stop();` etc

These lines declare a set of 5 functions.  Again, the argument lists are unspecified — so I'm going to treat them as having `(void)`.  These functions return a `funcptr`.  However, their own type is not `funcptr`.  This is the point made in the answer.

Indeed, treated as a name (without the parentheses), the type of `start`, `stop`, and `state1` through `state3` is `ptrfuncptr` — pointer to a function returning a `funcptr`.

#### Line 9: `ptrfuncptr state = start;`

The variable `state` is of type `ptrfuncptr`, and is initialized (without need for casting) to point at the function `start`.  Note that this does not call the function; it merely initializes a variable, just as if you have `int i = -37;`, it initializes a variable `i` of type `int` to the value `-37`.

#### Line 12: `state = (ptrfuncptr)(*state)();`

Time to get the bludgeons out.  This line contains a function call and a cast.

The original logic behind function pointers was the 'type mimics use' concept. For example, if you have:

```
int *p;
```

then in an expression, `*p` has the type `int`.  With function pointers, you have:

```
int (*intfuncptr)();
```

and in an expression, `(*intfuncptr)()` represents an `int`; it is the result of invoking the function pointed at by `intptrfunc`.  In pre-standard C, the `(*pointer_to_function)()` notation was the only way to use a pointer to function.  Standard C allows you to omit the `(*` and `)` around the pointer.

Thus, in modern notation, the line `state = (ptrfuncptr)(*state)();` could also be written `state = (ptrfuncptr)state();`.  When I learned C, this wasn't an option, so I still prefer the explicit 'this is invoking a function via a pointer to function' notation.  The FAQ does mention this.

So, the line calls the function pointed to by `state`, and captures the return value in `state`.  But the value returned by the function is a `funcptr`, not a `ptrfuncptr`, so we need to bludgeon the compiler into accepting that we know enough of what we're doing to remain silent.  So, the `(ptrfuncptr)` cast does that.

#### Line 17: `return (funcptr)state1;`

Since `start` returns a `funcptr`, but `state1` is a pointer to a function that returns a `funcptr`, the cast here is, once more, necessary to bludgeon the compiler into accepting the type mismatch.  Without parentheses after it, `state1` is just the name of the function, not an invocation of the function, and therefore has the type `ptrfuncptr` — pointer to a function returning a `funcptr`, not just `funcptr` which is what `start` is supposed to return.  So, the cast is necessary.

For more mind-blowing function pointers, see:

- [Understanding typedefs for function pointer in C — examples, hint and tips, please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591361/)
- [How `typedef` works for function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357520/)
- [Is it a good idea to `typedef`pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/) — general answer, no, but there's a strong exception for pointers to functions.
- [What are the various styles of defining a function returning a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844753/)

…and somewhere there's a question that discusses trivia like `state = (ptrfuncptr)(******state)();` (using notation from this Q&A), and the mulitple stars work too…

Comment: @fjardon:  Thanks.  I was writing up a comment for your answer, too: _It's surprising how often it happens that I'm typing away on my answer, after an hour with no answers being posted, and then someone else goes and posts an answer within a few seconds of mine.  I'm glad you agree with me on the line numbering — I've fixed the question._  You're under no obligation to delete your answer simply because there is another one.  But it is your judgement call.